# premier pro timeline

Tags: video, premiere, video-editor

I need to edit some clips for part of my graduate research to 200ms.
200ms are equivalent to 0.2 seconds.

Does the picture show this as 0.2 seconds?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have 25fps (25 frames per second) video, so each frame is 40ms long (1/25 second). That means 5 frames of video would be 200ms. Your image shows a 20 frame clip, so it's 800ms long.

Comment: Thank you! How does this look?

Comment: @crazygradstudent  That's two frames, or 80ms. The time line indicates hours:minutes:seconds:frames -- 00:00:00:05 is five frames -- so move the marker under ;05 and you'll have it